# Escape forward slash in R Markdown

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I cannot figure out how to escape a forward slash in markdown. I am building a personal website with blogdown (program R) and Hugo, and the forward slashes in my DOIs keep formatting as division rather than forward slashes.

**Problematic display:**

[image]

**Escaped:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

I thought I could escape them with a backslash, but the backslash appears in the output. Surprisingly can't find anything on this in markdown's documentation... how do I escape a forward slash?

Comment: Slash doesn't do anything special in Markdown, but maybe RMarkdown is different.

Comment: Interesting. The file is a .md extension, but when it gets parsed (?) by Hugo to build the site, it outputs a .html file with: doi:10.<sup>1088</sup>&frasl;<sub>1748</sub>-9326... so seems to think it is a math equation for some reason.

Comment: Found a work around by using the html code for a slash (&#47;), but seems like strange behavior.

Comment: You may want to set the option `fractions` to `false` for Blackfriday: https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/ Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I can't say for sure.

Comment: maybe use backticks to wrap the doi? or are those doi part of the auto-generated references?